# Show Login/Signup Errors with firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to show the error to the user while logging in if the information is incorrect. Such as invalid username/Password etc

```
 @IBAction func signIn(_ sender: Any) {

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {

            //self.createAlert(titleText: "Error", messageText: String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))

            return
        } else {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signInToTabBarVC", sender: nil)
        print("Signed In")

        }
    }



}
```

I also want to show sign up errors. Including email is already in use or username or password is too weak

```
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField.text! , password: passwordField.text!, completion: { (user: User?, error: Error?) in


        if error != nil {

            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return


        }

        let uid = user?.uid
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://vloggle-cb375.appspot.com").child("profile_picture").child(uid!)
        if let chosenImg = self.chosenImage, let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImg, 0.1) {

            storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                if error != nil {


                    return
                }

                    let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                    self.setUserInformation(profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl!, username: self.usernameField.text!, email: self.emailField.text!, uid: uid!)


                })

        }

        })



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can show error message with the help of `UIAlertView`

```
let dialog = UIAlertController(title: error!.localizedDescription, message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        dialog.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.present(dialog, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
```